# Android - making subtabs wit TabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

is it possible to create subtabs in tabs made by TabHost? If so, how? I was not able to find any valuable source or help in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to put a `TabActivity` inside a `Tab`.

Say you have `MainTabActivity` with two `Tabs`. First `Tab` can then hold `FirstSubTabActivity` and the second `Tab` could hold `SecondSubTabActivity`.

Here is an example:

**Main activity:**

```
public class MainTabActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent().setClass( this, FirstSubTabActivity.class );
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec( "FirstTab" ).setIndicator( "One" ).setContent( intent );
        tabHost.addTab( spec );

        intent = new Intent().setClass( this, SecondSubTabActivity.class );
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec( "SecondTab" ).setIndicator( "Two" ).setContent( intent );
        tabHost.addTab( spec );
    }
}
```

**First subactivity:**

```
public class FirstSubTabActivity extends TabActivity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
       TabHost.TabSpec spec;
       Intent intent;

       intent = new Intent().setClass( this, SomeActivity.class );
       spec = tabHost.newTabSpec( "SubTab" ).setIndicator( "One" ).setContent( intent );
       tabHost.addTab( spec );

       intent = new Intent().setClass( this, SomeOtherActivity.class );
       spec = tabHost.newTabSpec( "AnotherSubTab" ).setIndicator( "Two" ).setContent( intent );
       tabHost.addTab( spec );
   }
}
```

**Second subactivity:**

```
public class SecondSubTabActivity extends TabActivity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
       TabHost.TabSpec spec;
       Intent intent;

       intent = new Intent().setClass( this, SomeThirdActivity.class );
       spec = tabHost.newTabSpec( "ThirdSubTab" ).setIndicator( "One" ).setContent( intent );
       tabHost.addTab( spec );

       intent = new Intent().setClass( this, SomeFourthActivity.class );
       spec = tabHost.newTabSpec( "FourthSubTab" ).setIndicator( "Two" ).setContent( intent );
       tabHost.addTab( spec );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this shows manual adding of subtabs, do you have any ideas how to make it programatically without having to use 2 more activities?